# How to display a structure's instance as a string vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

My goal is be able to print out a `Structure` as a receipt without using a `SortedList`.

**Structure**:

```
Private Structure Facture
    Dim noClient As String
    Dim nom As String
    Dim prenom As String
    Dim adresse As String
    Dim ville As String
    Dim province As String
    Dim codePostal As String
    Dim courriel As String
    Dim noTel As String
    Dim noProduit As String
    Dim marque As String
    Dim modele As String
    Dim annee As String
    Dim couleur As String
    Dim categorie As String
    Dim noSerie As String
    Dim prix As String
    Dim dateVente As String
End Structure
```

**Structure Instance** :

```
Private Function getFacture(ByVal ID As Integer) As Facture
    Dim receipt As Facture
    receipt.noClient = mtxtNoClient.Text
    receipt.nom = txtNom.Text
    receipt.prenom = txtPrenom.Text
    receipt.adresse = txtAdresse.Text
    receipt.ville = txtVille.Text
    receipt.province = CboProvince.Text
    receipt.codePostal = mtxtCodePostal.Text
    receipt.courriel = txtCourriel.Text
    receipt.noTel = mtxtNoTel.Text
    receipt.noProduit = mtxtNoProduit.Text
    receipt.marque = txtMarque.Text
    receipt.modele = txtModele.Text
    receipt.annee = mtxtAnnee.Text
    receipt.couleur = txtCouleur.Text
    receipt.categorie = txtCategorie.Text
    receipt.noSerie = txtNoSerie.Text
    receipt.prix = mtxtPrix.Text
    receipt.dateVente = dtpickerDateVente.Text
    Return (receipt)

End Function
```

And I need to print this along side an Array of Strings.

**FORMAT** :

```
Private Sub btnAfficherVente_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAfficherVente.Click

    ' gotta read each line and print them as toString formatted for facturation 
    Dim infoProduit As String() = New String() {"No de client:", "Nom:", "Prénom:", "Adresse:", "Ville:", "Province:", "Code Postal:", "Courriel:", "Téléphone:",
        "No de produit:", "Marque:", "Modèle:", "Année:", "Couleur:", "Catégorie:", "No de série:", "Prix:", "Date de vente:"}

    'Output in facturation formatted text
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While i < infoProduit.Length
        If i = 9 Then
            txtFacturation.Text += vbCrLf + "==============================================" + vbCrLf
        End If
        txtFacturation.Text += String.Format("{0, -20}", infoProduit(i)) & vbTab & getFacture(i).ToString & vbCrLf
        i += 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT** :

[image]

I have looked at the documentation and multiple questions on StackOverflow. Most of the answers are in regards of using a `Dictionnary`, `Collection` or `SortedList`.

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method), the only thing I found was to Override the `ToString()` in the `Structure`, which would no work for me because that would mean I have to individually format them in `ToString` but that would mess the final output since I have to print it along side an Array of Strings.

Comment: Your `getFacture` doesn't make sense. It ignores the ID-parameter. You are also calling it in the loop with the index as parameter but you just need to use the same, single instance of  `Facture` because you want to get all fields of it.

Comment: You have to use `ID` to determine which property of the current facture to show. You don't need to create a new one every time and you can't just return the entire thing. For instance if `ID` is 0 return `noClient`, if `ID` is 1 return `nom` (and so on).

Comment: the `getFacture(i).ToString()` is wrong! you dpn't use `ID` param inside the `getFacture()` function.  Why you don't use a dictionary? You need to use reflecection to get properties by index which may be not required!

Comment: So I should return an Integer which is the ID position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a class instead of a structure. But you'll need a method inside the structure that will return the wanted text.

```
Private Structure Facture
    Dim noClient As String
    Dim nom As String
    Dim prenom As String
    Dim adresse As String
    Dim ville As String
    Dim province As String
    Dim codePostal As String
    Dim courriel As String
    Dim noTel As String
    Dim noProduit As String
    Dim marque As String
    Dim modele As String
    Dim annee As String
    Dim couleur As String
    Dim categorie As String
    Dim noSerie As String
    Dim prix As String
    Dim dateVente As String

    Function obtenirFactureTexte() As String

        Dim resultat As String = ""

        resultat &= "No de client: " & noClient & vbCrLf
        resultat &= "Nom: " & nom & vbCrLf
        resultat &= "Prénom: " & prenom & vbCrLf
        ' ...

        Return resultat
    End Function

End Structure

Sub Main()

    Dim nouvelleFacture As New Facture

    nouvelleFacture.noClient = "123"
    nouvelleFacture.nom = "Lagare"
    nouvelleFacture.prenom = "Bob"

    Console.Write(nouvelleFacture.obtenirFactureTexte())

End Sub
```

You can then use that method to output the result anywhere.

```
txtFacturation.Text = getFacture(i).obtenirFactureTexte()
```